# How can I pick out elements of an array with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this code:

```
        var answers = _.clone($scope.question.answers)
        var answers = {};
        $scope.question.answers.forEach(function (element, index) {
            answers[index].answerUid = element.answerUid;
            answers[index].response = element.response;
        });
```

Is there some way that I could simplify this using lodash ?

Comment: What's your data look like?

Comment: that's already quite simple, but as it looks like you are reducing a larger data structure to something else, think that `reduce` is a better choice. does what it says on the tin etc ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is unclear to my what it is you are trying to iterate over and what it is you expect to have at the end. For instance, the way the code in the question is currently written, this line will cause an error:

```
answers[index].answerUid = element.answerUid;
```

because it will read `answers[index]` from the `answers` object, get `undefined` and try to access the field `answerUid` of the `undefined` value.

At any rate, I can cover the major cases. If you want `answers` to be an array, then this would do it:

```
var answers = _.map($scope.question.answers,
                    _.partialRight(_.pick, "answerUid", "response"));
```

This works whether `$scope.question.answers` is an array or an `Object`. The `_.partialRight(_.pick, "answerUid", "response"))` call is equivalent to:

```
function (x) {
    return _.pick(x, ["answerUid", "response"]);
}
```

The `_.pick` function picks the two fields `answerUid` and `response` out of the object.

If `$scope.question.answers` is a key/value mapping and you want a correponding mapping in `answers`, then this would do it:

```
var answers = _.mapValues($scope.question.answers,
                          _.partialRight(_.pick, "answerUid", "response"));
```

All the solutions here have been tested but it is not impossible that I introduced a typo in transcription.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use lodash, native [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works just as well - assuming that answers is a straight up array (looks like you are using angular?).

```
 var answers = _.clone($scope.question.answers)
 var filteredAnswers = answers.reduce(function(working, current, index ){
     working.push({
        answerUid: current.answerUid,
        response: current.response
     });
     return working;
 },[]);
```

If that's confusing, here's another example of using reduce to sum an array of numbers:

```
[1,2,3].reduce(function(sum, current){return sum + current;},0); // 6
```

The zero at the end is the initial value passed into the callback (as sum above), and the value you return is passed on to the next call of the function. Keep returning, filter inside your function body, and away you go. Reduce can return whatever structure you like, not just single primitive values.

edit: it looked like you were assigning keys on an object with numeric values - if you need an object as opposed to an array, then that would be a bit different.

Comment: Just a note- native reduce will throw if `answers` is not an array, whereas lodash will short-circuit gracefully.

Comment: sure, as noted on the first line ;)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to wrap the function inside `unary` ([docs](https://lodash.com/docs#unary)). Otherwise you pass the key and the collection from iteratee to the `pick` function ([docs](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues)) and it can (must not) lead to unexpected results.

```
var answers = _.mapValues($scope.question.answers, _.unary(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'answerUid', 'response')));
```